# Jquery Cycle: How Can I Paginate the Pager?

Tags: jquery, cycle, pagination

I am using the Jquery cycle plug in with the pager.  I have a lot of items to page through. Is there a way I can add back and previous arrows to paginate the pager?

So I have like:

1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9

and I want the same but
<  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  >

Is there an elegant way to code this?  Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I do this on this site:
http://www.naomimorgulis.com/

Basically when it reaches the end of the pager I dynamically generate a new set of pagers with thumbnails.  I don't know if this is exactly elegant, but it works.

Answer (score -1):

Sure, just use the [`prev` and `next` parameters](http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/options.html) to specify which elements should be the next/prev buttons.

```
var $prev = $('<span id="prev">→</span>'),
    $next = $('<span id="next">←</span>'),
    $pager = $('<span id="pager" />');
$('foo').after($prev).after($pager).after($next).cycle({ prev: $prev, next: $next, pager: $pager });
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mathias/qzXwk/)